# Dialogflow (API.AI) how to match numbers that are valid words

Tags: actions-on-google, dialogflow-es

Trying to come up with the appropriate context for this:

What are my sales for store 4?

Where 4 is @sys.number.  It seems the engine refuses to see 4 as a number (it returns "for") and also 2 as a number (it returns "to")

What context pattern can I use to make the number be generated?

Sample here....

[image]

Comment: Can you provide some screen shots to illustrate the Intents you're currently using to try and capture the phrase?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply change your ask context.

What are my sales for store **number** four.
Whare are today's sales for store number four.